# Centering a .well Div in BootStrap Container Dive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrapper

I have an standard Bootstrap `<div>` with the `.container` class and an interior `<div>` with the `.well span9` class. I need to center the the `.well` div in the container but it always float to left! I think it is because of using `.span9` but how I can force the div to have  `.span9` class and also be centered?

here is the code which I have

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="well span9"> </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might be easier... unless you are dead-set on using span9

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="well span10 offset1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you use span10 and offset it by 1, it will always be centered as it is a 12 grid system (1+10+1). Also, you should add a `row` div under the container.

Or you could use `span8` and `offset2`...

If you are dead-set on span9 then you can add this CSS which will center it..

```
.well {
    margin:0 auto;
    float:none;
}
```